# What is the maximum size Plecostomus that can be kept in a 30 gallon tank?

Tags: aquarium, fish, pleco

We have a regular 30-gallon fish tank. We have two Plecostomus fish, and they are about 9 inches long. We feed them algae pellets regularly. They have been 9 inches long for years. We monitor the water very well, and haven't had any fish die in 5 years. These plecos have a good skin color and look healthy.

Are these fish too big for our tank? Should I try to put them up for adoption? Are they unhappy because they don't have enough space?

I Googled this but I didn't find out enough info to know what size pleco is too big for our tank.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your tank? If they're able to move freely in all directions (their length shouldn't be larger than the width of the tank for example), they look and act healthy, and water parameters are fine, I don't see any reason why you should put them up for adoption.